# Can I start a remote powershell session from a remote session?

Tags: powershell

I am able to successfully remote into one of the machines (**ComputerA**) in our enterprise at work using the following command
`Enter-PSSession`
Now can i start a new `Enter-PSSession` within this session to **ComputerB**? I am not able to do it. I get the following error:

```
Remote host method PushRunspace is not implemented.
    + CategoryInfo          :
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

I am able to start a session from a powershell prompt on **ComputerA** to **ComputerB**.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` inside another interactive session is not supported. Instead, try `Invoke-Command` to run commands on a remote computer while being in an interactive session.

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server-02
[Server-02]: PS C:\> Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server-03 -ScriptBlock { GCI C:\ } -Credential (Get-Credential)
```